# Cannot seem to get mouseover event to work with mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why the `mouseover` event doesn't work with mapbox gl.

```
map.on('load', function() {
  var geoJson = '{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            ...
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -118.6059,
                34.1829
            ]
        }
    }]
  }';


  map.addSource('someData', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: geoJson,
    cluster: true,
    clusterMaxZoom: 14
  });

  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'unclustered-markers',
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': 'someData',
    'layout': {
        'icon-image': 'circle-11'
    }
  });
});
```

So that part works and the coordinates are displayed on the map within the cluster. However, when I try the `mouseover` event, nothing happens.

```
map.on('mouseover',function(e) {
    console.log(e);                 // nothing is logged when I hover over the map or the points
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['unclustered-markers'] });
    ...
});
```

If I change that event to `click` then the event is logged to the console when I click on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the wrong event name. Note that is it `mousemove`, not `mouseover`. To fix this, change your code to:

```
map.on('mousemove',function(e) {
    console.log(e);                 
    //....
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/o870ufLr/ 
Open the console to see the events.

Comment: Oh wow haha thanks for pointing that out! I cannot believe I did that. For some reason I kept seeing or thinking about mouseover.... Thank you

Comment: Strictly speaking, `mousemove` is not the same as `mouseover`.

Answer (score 0):

GL JS does not fire the `mouseover` event despite firing `mousemove` and `moseout` events. I don't think there is a reason why we do not fire `mouseover`. We should add this event.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `mouseenter` and should be considered depending on your application. In case you have stumbled upon this question because Mapbox was giving you erratic behavior with missing popups, here is a work around to guarantee the popup will be above the `feature` the user hovered over.

Use Mapbox to handle the event and get the mouse coordinates like so:

```
map.on('mouseenter', 'layerID', (event) => {
    var x = event.originalEvent.clientX
    var y = event.originalEvent.clientY
```

Well then, it's a matter of using your favorite DOM handler and adding a `<div>` for the popup. Set the position of the popup to where the user hovered like so :

```
{left : `${x}`, top : `${y}`, position : 'absolute', zIndex : 1}
```